# How to call a function in a thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Consider this is a `class` that I have:

```
import threading

class SomeClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def func1(arg):
        # The body of code.

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func1(arg)
```

I want to call a function in a class in `run()` method. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You call the function in the `run()` method.

It seems like here that you might want to use a `@staticmethod` decorator, to eliminate the self-binding. This way, you can just `SomeClass.func1(arg)` ... Or you can add self as the first arg, or call it with alternate syntax.